# MS Access - Run Query based on User Choice from Drop Down List

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2013

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Access form where a user would pick a value from a drop down list and based on that choice a different query would run. For example if the user picks choice A then Query A would run, if B then Query B would run. I have already written the sql query that chooses which query would run based on what choice and it runs perfectly on its own. The problem occurs when I try to incorporate it within my form and add the criteria as  `[Forms]![myform]![myvalue]`, the query doesn't even run. I've tried to simplify the query where only simple SELECT FROM query should run when a user makes an input but it also doesn't run. I can't seem to make out where the problem is so I'd be very thankful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Create an unbound form, with the dropdown column/combo box that has the choices e.g A,b,c etc

Create a command button.

On the click event of the command button, add an IF statement.

In the images I attached, the following are the names I used.

1. Combo box has the name Combo0 and the caption choice
2. Command button has the name runquery, and the caption Run Query

[image: Query list]
[image: Choice list]
[image: VBA Code]